# Android R file and ADT14 and later Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases. 
 Invoke this fix to get more information.

```
        mRefreshView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.pull_to_refresh_header, this, false);
```

Happens in this line.
My R.java file did not change to the new so called no "final" format, it looks like this

```
 public static final class id {
    public static final int pull_to_refresh_header=0x7f060000;
    public static final int pull_to_refresh_image=0x7f060002;
    public static final int pull_to_refresh_progress=0x7f060001;
    public static final int pull_to_refresh_text=0x7f060003;
    public static final int pull_to_refresh_updated_at=0x7f060004;
}
```

What's the fix for this in the code since I cannot call R.layout.pull_to_refresh_header anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to ADT16 and everything seems back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

They say replace `switch`es with `if-else`s. Other than that no other modifications are needed. They say Eclipse can do this for you.

Comment: I had no switch statements. Anyway I updated to ADT16 and everything seems back to normal.